# Is there a practical way to implement wealth redistribution that isn't currently implemented?

Tags: taxes, marxism

A common goal of Marxist and other socialists is to redistribute wealth from the rich to the poor. Is there a practical way to accomplish this that isn't already being done?

- We already have an [estate tax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estate_tax_in_the_United_States)that is as high as 40%.
- We already have a [progressive income tax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_tax_in_the_United_States), as high as 39.6%.
- We already have sales taxes, property taxes, etc., which amount to large amounts on high dollar items.

Is there a practical way to redistribute wealth already accumulated by someone like Warren Buffet, that we currently aren't doing? What are these detailed plans if they exist?

Comment: 'wealth redistribution' is a loaded term, but regardless, you pretty much answered your own question. The 'practical way' to balance wealth across society is through taxes.

Comment: @DA., which term would you use? So, we already are redistributing wealth, no work is left to be done.

Comment: I'd probably use the term 'taxes'.

Comment: @DA., I don't think that's what Marxist are looking for. They want to free up capital by redistributing it from the hands of a few. Taxes didn't seem to be enough, from his [Manifesto](http://marx.eserver.org/1848-communist.manifesto/cm2.txt) it appears that a large amount of control would be needed (1-10 points)

Comment: Well, maybe the question needs some clarification. You talk about socialism and marxism, but then talk about US tax rates. The US isn't a socialist nor marxist state, but does use Taxes in an attempt at more equitably distributing wealth (which we could debate how well that's working).

Comment: @DA., it clearly isn't, because the state doesn't own the means of production. That doesn't mean that one of the goals of a Marxist state isn't to redistribute wealth from the hands of a few to the hands of many. This may just be a matter of degree, Marxists would want a 100% estate tax where we only have a 40% one. Marxists would want a 99% income tax bracket, where we have a nearly 40% one. I am curious why such a high rate is needed to redistribute the wealth, you would think that losing half of it to the state would suffice.

Comment: I guess I'm not following you. What does current US taxes have to do with Marxism and Socialism? I don't think a hypothetical Marxist in charge of the US would necessarily simply want higher tax rates. I imagine they'd want to rethink the entirety of our tax system.

Comment: @DA., it is quite simple really. Does the US already redistribute wealth? One of the goals of Marxism is to redistribute wealth, and since the US does this to so degree already, what practical steps could be taken (and what would those be)? It seems like [higher taxes](http://www.gallup.com/poll/161927/majority-wealth-evenly-distributed.aspx?utm_source=alert&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=syndication&utm_content=morelink&utm_term=All%20Gallup%20Headlines) would be acceptable, but at [what rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laffer_curve)?

Comment: Are you asking what steps a Marxist would take to turn the US tax code into a Marxist-based tax system but only via changing existing tax rates? This question sounds purely hypothetical with somewhat odd and arbitrary constraints and, as such, doesn't seem answerable in any meaningful way.

Comment: @DA., no, that isn't at all what I said.

Comment: Most developed countries have higher tax rates for the wealthy and thus a lower gini coefficient. So yeah, there are more effective ways.

Comment: @user1873 if that is not at all what you said, then I guess I need you to clarify. I'm still confused as to how/why you are connecting Marxism to US tax rates. Are you instead asking how the US could better distribute wealth in general?

Comment: @user1873 Just to clarify what Avi said - Much of Europe has tax rates in the 50% - 60% range.  Taxes in the United States are actually quite *low* by developed country standards.

Answer (score 5):

A key problem with your question is the use of inappropriate terminology:  a significant body of socialists and almost all Marxists reject the categories of "wealth," "rich" and "poor" as such, see instead "Capital," "bourgeoisie and "proletariat."  Even within social-democracy, labourism and progressivism there's often an awareness of the difference between "redistribution of wealth within capitalism," and "transfer of elements of the economy to national or social control."  The difference can be seen in terms of the difference between, say, a superannuation scheme of forced savings with forced government and employer co-payment and the rebuying of public-private partnership scheme constructed works into state control.

Nationalisation or socialisation by direct confiscation has been popular through history.  Either by legislative or executive action (decree) or by de facto plant seizures by workers cooperatives.  For the former, see various decrees on the confiscation of the property of emigres from the Bolshevik controlled geographic Soviets.  For examples of the later, see the direct seizure of productive property by workers councils in the Hungarian Revolution of 1956  (this later develops from sit-in strikes, or work ins or general strikes with factory occupations).  Seizure by confiscation as a result of criminal or civil trial has been less common, but it is presaged in Brecht's *Caucasian Chalk Circle*.

In terms of direct seizure there is a fair gulf of difference between nationalisation under state control and socialisation under workers' control.  In the former, capital usually merely becomes the property of the state, in the latter property-as-capital is transformed into something different, at least at first.

Finally, within capitalism, you've not considered wage or ancillary benefits as transfers to labour.  If the rate of profit taking is controlled, through forced reinvestment by company tax, one way to capitalise and to expand the consumer market to increase the velocity of capital (and thus capital taken even if the proportion is still lowered) is through wage rises.  Such as the period 1940-1970 in the US economy, where returns to labour increased faster than dividends or profit taking.

Comment: "Seizure by confiscation as a result of criminal or civil trial has been less common" - tell that to all the drug trafficing suspects whose vehicles - plausibly means of production - were nationalized by US law enforcement :) . Also +1 for the only answer formally based on Marxism.

Comment: @DVK ooh!  Good work.  I have been cretinistically formalist by forgetting the illegal sector.  "Mack the Knife" opposed socialisation or nationalisation just as much as Hearst.

Answer (score 1):

As long as we're on the topic, one already defined plan that hasn't been implemented is actual [Marxism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marxism), which despite popular belief, wasn't actually realized in the Soviet Union.

The stages in marxism are

> 1. Primitive Communism: as in co-operative tribal societies.
> 2. Slave Society: a development of tribal progression to city-state; aristocracy is born.
> 3. Feudalism: aristocrats are the ruling class; merchants evolve into capitalists.
> 4. Capitalism: capitalists are the ruling class, who create and employ the proletariat.
> 5. Socialism: workers gain class consciousness, and via proletarian revolution depose the capitalist dictatorship of the bourgeoisie,
>      replacing it in turn with dictatorship of the proletariat through
>      which the socialization of the means of production can be realized.
> 6. Communism: a classless and stateless society.

*from the wikipedia article on marsixm

The Soviet union Kinda skipped the 4th step, and went straight from Feudalism to Socialism.

Comment: ... Although their socialism had a significant stench of Feudalism due to local issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer the question, though I'm still a bit confused as to what is being asked. I'll assume you are asking

> Would higher tax rates in the United States help distribute wealth more evenly?

It may. But taxes are a bit more complicated than that.

As others have noted many other developed countries have much higher tax rates across the board. In return, they also have a lot more socialized programs and industries (such as health care).

Based on the tax rates of other nations, and the lower wealth gaps they have, one could come to the conclusion that yes, higher tax rates can help distribute the wealth more evenly.

However, another option is to reconsider what is being taxed. In the US, the wealthiest tend to not have high incomes, as such, higher income taxes don't affect them all that much. Changing how we tax investments and dividends could be one way to improve things.

Yet another option is to change how we handle tax deductions, rebates and incentives in the US. It's rare for anyone to pay the actual tax rates, as most everyone is eligible for deductions of some sort. The more money an entity makes, the more likely they can hire creative accountants and the less likely they are to paying anything close to the listed tax rates.

Now, how *practical* those solutions would still be up for debate. In the US we've long talked about simplifying our tax codes, yet it hasn't happened yet, so may not be a very practical suggestion in the end.

Comment: Again, downvoter care to explain? It would really help people improve/fix answers if explanations are provided with downvotes.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but studies done by the CRS and CBO indicate that, yes, in the US if you raise the income tax on the wealthy, it doesn't affect economic growth and decreases the gini coefficient. Sources: http://www.dpcc.senate.gov/files/documents/CRSTaxesandtheEconomy%20Top%20Rates.pdf, http://www.cbo.gov/publication/43694

Comment: True, but in terms of a 'practical things that haven't been implemented yet' I think rethinking capital gains taxation might be a more effective way to handle it. (Still not entirely clear on the question, though...)